# Is it illegal to hack twitter accounts and websites belonging to ISIS?

Tags: hacking

In particular, ISIS twitter accounts, networks, and propaganda sites.

Would the US government condone such cybercrime? Would they even encourage people to try? I have heard stories of ISIS defaming western websites, and I am more than confident people in the US would possess the technical skill.

I personally would not attempt it for the record, but is this legal in the US or other countries?

Comment: The law does not make exceptions for crime just because the target is disliked, if that's what you're asking. You can't murder someone just because the entire town hates them.

Comment: It's up to Congress.  Right now there's no special exception for hacking ISIS.

Comment: You aren't hacking _ISIS_, you're hacking _Twitter_.

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that the US, or any government, would condone any kind of crime.

The reason for this is that the law must be seen to be impartial and applied fairly to all those subject to it.

What happens if tomorrow, the government decides they don't like you?

It is possible that this type of activity, or activity amounting to it, would be sanctioned in *specific, authorised* cases.

But the government throwing a lynch mob at anyone is a bad idea for order and a peaceful society.